# Check if set of columns with specific names exists in a mysql table

Tags: mysql

How could I get if are there columns in a table with a specific name. I came across with this idea:

```
SHOW COLUMNS 
FROM analyzer_log LIKE 'id'
```

This is great but I'd like to get information about multiple columns at a time. I tried adding more columns but the query died of syntax error:

```
SHOW COLUMNS 
FROM analyzer_log LIKE 'id' OR 'user_id'
```

I dont want PHP to fire an SQL query for each columns I want to ascertain about. In fact it would be more effective if there was any way to get if all the desired columns exist with only one query and just return a true or false. If any of the columns not exist I'd like return false.

Answer (score 0):

use SELECT like that :-

```
SELECT 
    column_name
FROM 
    information_schema.columns
WHERE 
    table_name='analyzer_log'
    AND column_name LIKE 'id%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW Columns
FROM analyzer_log 
WHERE field IN ('id', 'user_id')
```

or if you need columns similar to 'id'

```
SHOW COLUMNS

FROM analyzer_log LIKE '%id%'
```